# Different length and width for checkerboard texture

Tags: texturing

I am trying to create a checkerboard texture which is 5 squares wide and a modifiable amount of squares long to fill a long plane. However, I can only figure out how to get the texture to be 5 tiles wide and long. How can I set the amount of tiles lengthwise so they are squares and not long rectangles as in the screenshot?
[image: Node setup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a **Mapping** node and a **Texture Coordinate** node as follows:

[image]

The *Scale* parameter on the **Mapping** node will control your checker's width.

Comment: The question is closed, so I cannot enter my own answer. While it is no problem to scale the tiles with a _Mapping Node_, when using the _Generated_ output you will always have to calculate the scale factor in relation to the object's dimensions to make sure the tiles are square or roughly judge by view. When you use _Object_ instead they will always be square without scaling, no matter how long the object is. The advantage if you want to use it for wall or floor tiles: if you want to use real world dimensions, you can simply enter the desired size in the texture's _Scale_ value.

Comment: Similar for the _Brick Texture_: if you use _Object_ coordinates and set the texture's scale to 1, you can enter width, height and mortar values to fit them to real world dimensions.